# Perform lookup in tensorflow map

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have a TF Dataset with the following schema:

```py
tf_features = {
 'searched_destination_id': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64, default_value=0),
 'booked_acc_id': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64, default_value=0),
 'user_id': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64, default_value=0),;
}
```

I also have a dict like:

```py
candidates = {'111': [123, 444, ...], '222': [555, 888, ...]...}
```

I'd like to perform a map operation in the following way:

```py
ds.map(lambda x, y: {**x, 'candidates': candidates[x['searched_destination_ufi'].numpy()]})
```

However I always get: `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`

when I remove the `.numpy()` I get `TypeError: Tensor is unhashable. Instead, use tensor.ref() as the key.`

Do you suggest any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `dataset.map` works in graph mode, where calling `.numpy()` on a tensor is not possible. You could try using `tf.py_function` to include the candidates `dict` into your dataset:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf_features = {
 'searched_destination_ufi': ['111', '222'],
 'booked_hotel_ufi': [2, 4],
 'user_id': [3, 2]
}

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf_features)

candidates = {'111': [123, 444], '222': [555, 888]}

def py_func(x):
  x = x.numpy().decode('utf-8')
  return candidates[x]


ds = ds.map(lambda x: {**x, 'candidates': tf.py_function(py_func, [x['searched_destination_ufi']], [tf.int32]*2)})
for x in ds:
  print(x)
```

```
{'searched_destination_ufi': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'111'>, 'booked_hotel_ufi': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=2>, 'user_id': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=3>, 'candidates': <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([123, 444], dtype=int32)>}
{'searched_destination_ufi': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'222'>, 'booked_hotel_ufi': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=4>, 'user_id': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=2>, 'candidates': <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([555, 888], dtype=int32)>}
```

Note that `[tf.int32]*2` corresponds to the length of the lists in `candidates`.

For a more sophisticated approach, you can use `tf.lookup.StaticHashTable` and `tf.gather`, which will both work in graph mode:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf_features = {
 'searched_destination_ufi': ['111', '222'],
 'booked_hotel_ufi': [2, 4],
 'user_id': [3, 2]
}

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf_features)

candidates = {'111': [123, 444], '222': [555, 888]}
keys = list(candidates.keys())
values = tf.constant(list(candidates.values()))

table = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(
    tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(tf.constant(keys), tf.range(len(keys))),
    default_value=-1)

ds = ds.map(lambda x: {**x, 'candidates': tf.gather(values, [table.lookup(x['searched_destination_ufi'])])})
for x in ds:
  print(x)
```

```
{'searched_destination_ufi': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'111'>, 'booked_hotel_ufi': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=2>, 'user_id': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=3>, 'candidates': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=array([[123, 444]], dtype=int32)>}
{'searched_destination_ufi': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'222'>, 'booked_hotel_ufi': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=4>, 'user_id': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=2>, 'candidates': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=array([[555, 888]], dtype=int32)>}
```

If the candidates field is of variable length use a ragged tensor and the second approach, the rest of the code remains the same:

```
candidates = {'111': [123, 444], '222': [555, 888, 323]}
keys = list(candidates.keys())
values = tf.ragged.constant(list(candidates.values()))
```

```
{'searched_destination_ufi': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'111'>, 'booked_hotel_ufi': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=2>, 'user_id': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=3>, 'candidates': <tf.RaggedTensor [[123, 444]]>}
{'searched_destination_ufi': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'222'>, 'booked_hotel_ufi': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=4>, 'user_id': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=2>, 'candidates': <tf.RaggedTensor [[555, 888, 323]]>}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer why should I use the second solution rather than the first one? is it better in performance?

Comment: Good question, yes graph mode execution usually performs better. See this for more information: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs#seeing_the_speed-up

Comment: Ok Thanks it worked!. I have a question, what if my `candidates` field is of variable length?

Comment: Then you will definitely need to use the second approach and values will be a ragged tensor. See updated answer. @3nomis